# Suggestions - plenty of countries do not appear in the returned data

Tags: here-api

When trying to get suggestions at https://autocomplete.geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/suggest.json?query=search_string
for the following strings: "Korea", "China", "Egypt", "United Arab Emirates", the result is weird: some obscure addresses appear, but no countries. What is even more funny, "Sudan" gives the "South Sudan" as a country, but no (North) Sudan. Is this how it should be? For example the result for the "Korea" is:

```
{
"suggestions": [
    {
        "label": "United States, NY, New York, Koreatown",
        "language": "en",
        "countryCode": "USA",
        "locationId": "NT_7wUYOjyc5nhxpMHPtLSTuB",
        "address": {
            "country": "United States",
            "state": "NY",
            "county": "New York",
            "city": "New York",
            "district": "Koreatown",
            "postalCode": "10001"
        },
        "matchLevel": "district"
    },
    {
        "label": "United States, NY, Airmont, Korean War Veterans Memorial Hwy",
        "language": "en",
        "countryCode": "USA",
        "locationId": "NT_kA6TbLAbwsSLEA8vabyxDB",
        "address": {
            "country": "United States",
            "state": "NY",
            "county": "Rockland",
            "city": "Airmont",
            "street": "Korean War Veterans Memorial Hwy",
            "postalCode": "10901"
        },
        "matchLevel": "street"
    },
    {
        "label": "United States, OH, Piqua, Korean War Veterans Memorial Hwy",
        "language": "en",
        "countryCode": "USA",
        "locationId": "NT_vccsaqFIU9eMsXqxfj0UMA",
        "address": {
            "country": "United States",
            "state": "OH",
            "county": "Miami",
            "city": "Piqua",
            "street": "Korean War Veterans Memorial Hwy",
            "postalCode": "45356"
        },
        "matchLevel": "street"
    },
    {
        "label": "United States, NY, Spring Valley, Korean War Veterans Memorial Hwy",
        "language": "en",
        "countryCode": "USA",
        "locationId": "NT_oWAdxNTgggvSioBhhX7LAD",
        "address": {
            "country": "United States",
            "state": "NY",
            "county": "Rockland",
            "city": "Spring Valley",
            "street": "Korean War Veterans Memorial Hwy",
            "postalCode": "10977"
        },
        "matchLevel": "street"
    }
]
```

}

far from what one could expect.

Comment: Can you edit the question to add details regarding how you are using the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search for countries with border disputes in Autocomplete has a bug and we are about to fix it.

Comment: This sounds reasonable indeed.

Answer (score 0):

The API at https://autocomplete.geocoder.api.here.com is the **Geocoder Autocomplete API**, which is useful to autocomplete addresses.

It looks like the [Places Search API](https://developer.here.com/documentation#places) would better suit to what you need.

For example, the following request with the query string "*korea*" returns **South Korea**, **North Korea** and **Korea** (looks like there is an administrative area in India which has that name):

```
curl \
  -H 'X-Map-Viewport:-2.8666,-32.6068,176.4302,65.5563' \
  --get 'https://places.api.here.com/places/v1/autosuggest' \
    --data-urlencode 'app_code={{APP_CODE}}' \
    --data-urlencode 'app_id={{APP_ID}}' \
    --data-urlencode 'pretty=true' \
    --data-urlencode 'q=korea' \
    --data-urlencode 'result_types=place' \
    --data-urlencode 'size=5'
```

Comment: Well, I have tried the query and this is what I got: a restaurant in Thailand, a shop in India, a restaurant in Thailand, a clothing shop in Indonesia, another restaurant in Thailand. Quite a different result.

Comment: I think with the same input, besides credentials, we should have the same output. Maybe you didn't pass the `size` parameter? Also once you get the response you can filter to keep only the objects with `category: administrative-region`. Would be nice to be able to filter by category upfront, but I'm not sure it's possible.

Comment: This should be the case, but definitely it is not. I was unable to get any response with an entry of a type: `administrative-region`.  `/discover/search` , however, produces the result similar to what you described, i.e. South Korea, North Korea (no 'Korea' in general), but close enough. So I guess this is the enpoint you suggested.